# Python nested for loop counting downwards

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I have an assignment to create a counting down `for` loop. The instructions are to get the results to be as follows:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

I'm probably making this to be more difficult than it actually is, but I'm quite new to Python.

So far, my script is as follows:

```
def print_figure():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        for count in range(i):
            print(12345, end='')
        print()
```

Which is resulting in:

```
1234512345123451234512345
12345123451234512345
123451234512345
1234512345
12345
```

I'm not asking for an answer, just a pointer in the right direction of where I can make a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there; you are printing the number `12345` over and over again, instead of using `count`, which ranges from 0 through to 4 in the first loop, 0 to 3 in the second, etc.

You want to print `count` itself, but either add one or adjust the range in which it loops to run from 1 to `i + 1`:

```
def print_figure():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        for count in range(1, i + 1):
            print(count, end='')
        print()
```

or use:

```
def print_figure():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        for count in range(i):
            print(count + 1, end='')
        print()
```

Demo:

```
>>> def print_figure():
...     for i in range(5, 0, -1):
...         for count in range(1, i + 1):
...             print(count, end='')
...         print()
... 
>>> print_figure()
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

The other approach would be to use a string `'12345'` and indexing into that; `'12345'[0]` is `'1'`, etc:

```
def print_figure():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        for count in range(i):
            print('12345'[count], end='')
        print()
```

but then you can just use slicing and get rid of the nested loop altogether:

```
def print_figure():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        print('12345'[:i])
```

because `'12345'[:3]` returns the first 3 characters of the string, printing `123`.

Comment: I have the feeling the OP was halfway between that and `"12345"[count]`

Comment: This was great. Thanks guys. I was trying to explain it to someone earlier while I was out and the idea of an index and a slice came to mind. I just wasn't sure how to input that. 

Fantastic! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

replace the last 2 lines :

```
        print(12345, end='')
    print()
```

with

```
        print(count),
    print ''
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach would be to take a string a remove the last item at every iteration :

```
value = '12345'
while value:
    print value
    value = value[:-1]
```

The upside is that you can easily replace `12345` with any string, of any length.